# Removing string between two symbol in line

Tags: linux, sed, awk, command

I am trying to remove a string between two symbol in line from a csv file. Here is my sample file :

```
1.1.1.1,A-B:,awef.C.D.E
1.1.1.2,A-B:,few.C.D.E
1.1.1.3,A-B:,dfs.C.D
1.1.1.4,A-B:,few.C.D
1.1.1.5,A-B:,fdsferger.C.D.E
1.1.1.6,A-B:,wef.C.D
1.1.1.7,A-B:,jty.C.D.E
```

The output would be like this :

```
1.1.1.1,A-B:,C.D.E
1.1.1.2,A-B:,C.D.E
1.1.1.3,A-B:,C.D
1.1.1.4,A-B:,C.D
1.1.1.5,A-B:,C.D.E
1.1.1.6,A-B:,C.D
1.1.1.7,A-B:,C.D.E
```

Any way I can achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `awk` command can do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub("[^.]*.","",$3);print}'
```

It basically divides each line into the three comma-separated fields then removes the initial part of the third field, up to and including the first `.` character.

Then it simply outputs them again.

See the following transcript for a demonstration:

```
pax> echo '1.1.1.1,A-B:,awef.C.D.E
1.1.1.2,A-B:,few.C.D.E
1.1.1.3,A-B:,dfs.C.D
1.1.1.4,A-B:,few.C.D
1.1.1.5,A-B:,fdsferger.C.D.E
1.1.1.6,A-B:,wef.C.D
1.1.1.7,A-B:,jty.C.D.E' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub("[^.]*.","",$3);print}'

1.1.1.1,A-B:,C.D.E
1.1.1.2,A-B:,C.D.E
1.1.1.3,A-B:,C.D
1.1.1.4,A-B:,C.D
1.1.1.5,A-B:,C.D.E
1.1.1.6,A-B:,C.D
1.1.1.7,A-B:,C.D.E
```

Comment: +1: Can be shortened to `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub(/[^.]+./,"",$3)}1' file`

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks, that was quick response :D. also learn more about awk command

Comment: @jaypal: thanks for the suggestions. I've used the FS/sub ones but I'd prefer the readability of `print` over the bizarre awk `1` style :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo no worries. I was just being cheap on extra keywords. I agree, readability should always triumph. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` that should do:

```
awk '{sub(/:,[^.]*\./,":,")}1' file
1.1.1.1,A-B:,C.D.E
1.1.1.2,A-B:,C.D.E
1.1.1.3,A-B:,C.D
1.1.1.4,A-B:,C.D
1.1.1.5,A-B:,C.D.E
1.1.1.6,A-B:,C.D
1.1.1.7,A-B:,C.D.E
```

Comment: `sed` by default supports `BRE` hence the use of `-r` switch to turn `ERE` on. `awk` by default supports `ERE` so `+` would work just fine.

Comment: If you have an input line with the data like: `1.1.1.7,A-B:,C.D.E` it will become `1.1.1.7,A-B:,.C.D.E` with `+`, so `*` is ok.

Comment: Not sure if I follow? How would you get that output?

Comment: If a line does not have data between `:.` like this `echo -e "1.1.1.6,A-B:,wef.C.D\n1.1.1.7,A-B:,.C.D.E"`.  One line has `,wef.`, the other `,.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed also

```
sed -r 's/(.*:,)([a-z]*.)(.*)/\1\3/g'

 (or)

sed -r 's/:,[^.]+\./:,/' file
```

Comment: or `sed -r 's/:,[^.]+\./:,/' file`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\(.*,\)[^.]*\./\1/' file
```

Use greed to gather up all the columns but the last and then delete upto and including the first `.`.